# Jquery jScrollPane initialization issue due to scrollHeight and scrollWidth set to 0

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have 3 different divs, all are AJAX populated. jScrollpane is not working in one of my div irrespective of whatever rendering order i tried.

After some debugging the plugin i found out the problem lies in this particular line `contentHeight = pane[0].scrollHeight;`, where the scrollHeight & width is always 0. below the complete snippet

```
            pane.css('overflow', 'auto');
            if (s.contentWidth) {
                contentWidth = s.contentWidth;
            } else {
                contentWidth = pane[0].scrollWidth;
            }
            contentHeight = pane[0].scrollHeight;
            pane.css('overflow', '');

            percentInViewH = contentWidth / paneWidth;
            percentInViewV = contentHeight / paneHeight;
            isScrollableV = percentInViewV > 1;

            isScrollableH = percentInViewH > 1;

            if (!(isScrollableH || isScrollableV)) {
              elem.removeClass('jspScrollable');
                pane.css({
                    top: 0,
                    width: container.width() - originalPaddingTotalWidth
                });
                removeMousewheel();
                removeFocusHandler();
                removeKeyboardNav();
                removeClickOnTrack();
```

`pane` is a newly created jsPane that appended to the original elem

```
pane = $('<div class="jspPane" />').css('padding', originalPadding).append(elem.children());
                    container = $('<div class="jspContainer" />')
                        .css({
                            'width': paneWidth + 'px',
                            'height': paneHeight + 'px'
                        }
                    ).append(pane).appendTo(elem);
```

why is it the scrollHeight is always 0 for this particular div? also other 2 divs are top level (only body is the parent), but the problematic div is very deep. Got 4 parent divs on top of that. I suspect the the problem is due to some height settings in any of the parent divs. But couldn't figure out where?